# How to find within all the objects of json in Python?

Tags: python

I have a json:

```
{
"total": 22,
"items": [
{
"id": 196,
"name": "Актау",
"code": "aktau",
"country": {
"name": "Казахстан",
"code": "kz"
}
},

{
"id": 167,
"name": "Актобе",
"code": "aktobe",
"country": {
"name": "Казахстан",
"code": "kz"
}
},

{
"id": 67,
"name": "Алматы",
"code": "almaty",
"country": {
"name": "Казахстан",
"code": "kz"
}
}
]
}
```

I need to print a "code" for every object within this json.
Can you please help?
What i'm asking is, can you somehow put all the objects in one brackets, like this?

```
json_response["items"][0, 1, 2]["country"]["code"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
result = [element["country"]["code"] for element in json_response["items"]]
```

Alternatively, you can use a normal for loop:

```
result = []
for element in json_response["items"]:
   result.append(element["country"]["code"])
```

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot do that kind of things but you can write a *list comprehension* that is close to what you want:

```py
[item["country"]["code"] for item in json_response["items"]]
```

This is equivalent to:

```py
[
   json_response["country"]["code"][0],
   json_response["country"]["code"][1],
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
J = {
    "total": 22,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 196,
            "name": "Актау",
            "code": "aktau",
            "country": {
                "name": "Казахстан",
                "code": "kz"
            }
        },

        {
            "id": 167,
            "name": "Актобе",
            "code": "aktobe",
            "country": {
                "name": "Казахстан",
                "code": "kz"
            }
        },

        {
            "id": 67,
            "name": "Алматы",
            "code": "almaty",
            "country": {
                "name": "Казахстан",
                "code": "kz"
            }
        }
    ]
}

print(*[j['code'] for j in J['items']])
```